# What is the real purpose of the $VERSION variable in Perl?

Tags: perl, version

I've read that it's considered good practice to always include a `$VERSION` number in all of your Perl scripts, but I never fully understood the purpose.

What do you really gain by including a version number in your script?

Comment: Where have you read that? Maybe there's some other context that's important.

Comment: @briandfoy, Honestly I don't remember. :(  I read it somewhere a while ago and have just been including a version number in all of my scripts since then without questioning why, but I never really knew the purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only modules, and only those pushed to CPAN really benefit from specifying `$VERSION`. There's not much use for it in a script except to use a familiar name rather than inventing a new one if you want the script's version to be accessible.

Primary uses:

- CPAN uses it as the version of the distribution, allowing it to index different versions of the same distribution.
- `cpan` and `cpanm` uses it to check if an installed module is of sufficiently high level to meet the required minimum version of a dependency.

As brian d foy mentioned, it can also be checked by `use Foo 1.23;`, but most people avoid this in favour of specifying the required versions of dependencies in their distribution's META file. This allows `cpan` and `cpanm` to update the dependency if needed (where use using `use Foo 1.23;` would cause the installation to fail during testing). Due to the lack of use of the feature, it's hardly a primary use.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify a minimum version of a module in the `use` statement:

```
 use Foo 1.23;
```

When Perl loads that module, it looks at the `$VERSION` variable to check that it's equal to or greater than that number. That way you get the right set of features and fixes.

The CPAN clients use `$VERSION` to determine if you are up-to-date or if you should install the latest version of a module.

For programs or scripts, you typically don't need a `$VERSION`.